# SQL Server : Bulk insert a Datatable into 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

Consider this datatable :

```
word             wordCount         documentId
----------       -------          ---------------
Ball               10                   1
School             11                   1
Car                 4                   1
Machine             3                   1 
House               1                   2
Tree                5                   2 
Ball                4                   2
```

I want to insert these data into two tables with this structure :

```
Table WordDictionary
(
   Id int, 
   Word nvarchar(50), 
   DocumentId int
)

Table WordDetails
(
   Id int, 
   WordId int, 
   WordCount int
)
FOREIGN KEY (WordId) REFERENCES WordDictionary(Id)
```

But because I have thousands of records in initial table, I have to do this just in one transaction (batch query) for example using bulk insert can help me doing this purpose.

But the question here is how I can separate this data into these two tables `WordDictionary` and `WordDetails`.

For more details :

Final result must be like this :

Table `WordDictionary`:

```
 Id              word 
----------       -------
1                  Ball
2                  School
3                  Car
4                  Machine
5                  House
6                  Tree
```

and table `WordDetails` :

```
 Id              wordId         WordCount           DocumentId
----------       -------        -----------        ------------
1                  1                 10                1
2                  2                 11                1
3                  3                 4                 1
4                  4                 3                 1
5                  5                 1                 2
6                  6                 5                 2
7                  1                 4                 2
```

Notice :

The words in the source can be duplicated so I must check word existence in table `WordDictionary` before any insert record in these tables and if a word is found in table `WordDictionary`, the just found `Word ID` must be inserted into table `WordDetails` (please see Word Ball)

Finally the 1 M$ problem is: this insertion must be done as fast as possible.

Comment: please saw your work?

Comment: here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Bulk Insert cannot do any "if exists" checks or stuff like that. EIther you want that data in the database really fast - then use `BULK INSERT` but you cannot do anything but just quickly load the data - or then use a "normal" scripted insert that can check for existance of rows etc. - but that'll be orders of magnitude slower than a  `BULK INSERT` - take your pick

Answer (score 0):

This is the query. I'm using temp table to be able to test.

if you use the 2 CTEs, you'll be able to generate the final result

**1.Setting up a sample data for test.**

```
create table #original (word varchar(10), wordCount int, documentId int)

insert into #original values
('Ball',               10,                   1),
('School',             11,                   1),
('Car',                 4,                   1),
('Machine',             3,                   1), 
('House',               1,                   2),
('Tree',                5,                   2), 
('Ball',                4,                   2)
```

**2. Use cte1 and cte2. In your real database, you need to replace #original with the actual table name you have all initial records.**

```
;with cte1 as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by word) Id, word
from #original
group by word
)
select * into #WordDictionary
from cte1

;with cte2 as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by #original.word) Id, Id as wordId,
    #original.word, #original.wordCount, #original.documentId
from #WordDictionary 
  inner join #original on #original.word = #WordDictionary.word
)
select * into #WordDetails
from cte2


select * from #WordDetails
```

This will be data in #WordDetails

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Id | wordId |  word   | wordCount | documentId |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Ball    |        10 |          1 |
|  2 |      1 | Ball    |         4 |          2 |
|  3 |      2 | Car     |         4 |          1 |
|  4 |      3 | House   |         1 |          2 |
|  5 |      4 | Machine |         3 |          1 |
|  6 |      5 | School  |        11 |          1 |
|  7 |      6 | Tree    |         5 |          2 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: If there are not thousands records, this approach is a good idea .But if there are  10,000 records , your query will be very slow because your join is on strings( original.word = #WordDictionary.word) and it will be worse specially if the data would be in  unicode format ( for example for Non English words), ** For more Info I must add this note that this query would be crashed when you caught to 1000 records.see this error ** : The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Comment: @EhsanShirvan, the first INSERT INTO, is just for making some sample data. You only need to use cte1 and cte2. Assume #original table is the sample data you mentioned at the beginning of your question, that contains all your raw data. Then using cte1 and cte2 you can populate your dictionary tables. so just ignore the "insert into" and use cte1 and cte2 and instead of #original, use your original table name in queries

Comment: I have about 100,000 primary records that must be separated into two tables that I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just load the table the first time without any updates to the table over time you could potentially do it this way (I'm assuming you've already created the tables you're loading into):

You can put all of the distinct words from the datatable into the WordDictionary table first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word
INTO WordDictionary 
FROM datatable;
```

Then after you populate your WordDictionary you can then use the ID values from it and the rest of the information from datatable to load your WordDetails table:

```
SELECT WD.Id as wordId, DT.wordCount as WordCount, DT.documentId AS DocumentId
INTO WordDetails
FROM datatable as DT
INNER JOIN WordDictionary AS WD ON WD.word = DT.word
```

Answer (score 0):

There a little discrepancy between declared table schema and your example data, but it was solved:

**1) Setup**

```
-- this the table with the initial data
-- drop table DocumentWordData
create table DocumentWordData
(
    Word NVARCHAR(50),
    WordCount INT,
    DocumentId INT
)
GO

-- these are result table with extra information (identity, primary key constraints, working foreign key definition)

-- drop table WordDictionary
create table WordDictionary
(
   Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_WordDictionary PRIMARY KEY, 
   Word nvarchar(50)
)
GO

-- drop table WordDetails
create table WordDetails
(
   Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_WordDetails PRIMARY KEY, 
   WordId int CONSTRAINT FK_WordDetails_Word REFERENCES WordDictionary, 
   WordCount int,
   DocumentId int
)
GO
```

**2) The actual script to put data in the last two tables**

```
begin tran
-- this is to make sure that if anything in this block fails, then everything is automatically rolled back
set xact_abort on

-- the dictionary is obtained by considering all distinct words
insert into WordDictionary (Word)
select distinct Word 
from DocumentWordData

-- details are generating from initial data joining the word dictionary to get word id
insert into WordDetails (WordId, WordCount, DocumentId)
SELECT W.Id, DWD.WordCount, DWD.DocumentId
FROM DocumentWordData DWD
    JOIN WordDictionary W ON W.Word = DWD.Word
commit

-- just to test the results
select * from WordDictionary
select * from WordDetails
```

I expect this script to run very fast, if you do not have a very large number of records (millions at most).